# How can I use v-html on the vue?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I try like this :

```
<template>
    ...
    <div v-html="test"></div>
    ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    test: null,
  }),
  mounted () {
    let a = {country: "England:↵ - Liverpool↵ - Chelsea↵ - Arsenal↵ - MU↵ - City"}
    this.test = a.country
  }
}
</script>
```

The result :

```
England:↵ - Liverpool↵ - Chelsea↵ - Arsenal↵ - MU↵ - City
```

I have used v-html, but that doesn't work. there should be a new line for each word

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should  use `<br>`  for new line not `↵`

Comment: Use a `<pre>` tag or add `style="white-space:pre-line"` to your `<div>`. FYI, `↵` is not a newline character. It's literally a little right-angle arrow glyph

Comment: @Ahmad Mobaraki The json is response of API

Comment: @Phil Yeah. But the data json from API. I just to get the data

Comment: `↵` is not HTML

Comment: @Zim So what the solution?

Comment: it's better to set the `\n` for `↵` and after that in the computed method explode it to array and show it as array of course  you can do this with `↵`
@SuccessMan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to literally replace `↵`, you can do it by:

```js
let a = {
  country: "England:↵ - Liverpool↵ - Chelsea↵ - Arsenal↵ - MU↵ - City"
};
this.test = a.country.replace(/↵/g, '<br/>');
```

**[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-rgb-ex3p9)**

Answer (score 1):

We can't use markdown character directly. so we need use replace function for replace character with tag.

```
this.test = a.country.replace(/\u21B5/g,'<br/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using markdown try the following

```html
<template>
    <div v-html="$options.filters.markhtml(test)"></div>
</template>

<script>
import marked from 'marked'
export default {
    data(){
      return {
          test: null,
      }
    },
    mounted () {
        let a = {country: "England: \n- Liverpool \n- Chelsea \n- Arsenal \n- MU \n- City"}
        this.test = a.country
    },
    filters: {
        markhtml: function (markdown) {
            if (typeof markdown !== 'undefined') {
                return marked(markdown)
            }
                return null
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

You have to use `marked` and import it like show in the code.

Below is a [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kikuyu1/rkL7je8o/17/). I hope my answer is helpful

Comment: your code snippet says `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"`