# How to render line-break ↵ in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to render a line break whenever there's a ↵ in Vue.

I followed [How can I use v-html on the vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305027/how-can-i-use-v-html-on-the-vue) but I am unable to follow.

What I have tried:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      a: {
        country: "England:↵ - Liverpool↵ - Chelsea↵ - Arsenal↵ - MU↵ - City",
      },
      testObj: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    jsonFunc() {
      return (this.testObj = this.a.country.replace(/↵/g, "<br/>"));
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Vue
    {{ jsonFunc }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div v-html="jsonFunc"></div>` [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-pasteur-24x2v?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-html` directive

```js
<template>
  <div >
    Vue
    <span v-html='jsonFunc'></span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      a: {
        country: "England:↵ - Liverpool↵ - Chelsea↵ - Arsenal↵ - MU↵ - City",
      },
      testObj: "",
    };
  },

  computed: {
    jsonFunc() {
      return (this.testObj = this.a.country.replace(/↵/g, "<br/>"));
    },
  },
};
</script>
```