# How to render a line break ↵ in table - Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am facing exactly the same problem as [How to render line-break ↵ in VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66926538/how-to-render-line-break-in-vuejs).

I want to render a line break whenever there's an ↵ in Vue, with a value within a table and the data for the table is coming from API as a JSON object. So, I am unable to follow the accepted answer for the question that I linked (as I am not sure exactly how to render the linebreak inside a table).

What I have tried:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: ["first_name", "last_name", "age", "hobbies"],
      items: [
        {
          isActive: true,
          age: 40,
          first_name: "Dickerson",
          last_name: "Macdonald",
          hobbies : "Reading↵ Singing"
        },
        { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: "Larsen", last_name: "Shaw", hobbies : "Surfing↵ Stamp Collecting↵ Games" },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Questions are supposed to be self-contained: don't link to external code **instead** of posting the code in the question (having a link in addition to code in the question is fine). Also: if you face the *exact same* problem, then tell us why the answer in the linked-to question didn't help you!

Comment: Its not external code. I created that codesandbox so people who are trying to "help" find it useful as they can see live result also.

Comment: It's external to Stackoverflow. Your question is supposed to be answerable with just the information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution while iterating over the elements of `items` in a `computed` property, and add `white-space: pre-line;` styling to the `b-table` to preserve the new lines:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data() {
    return {
      fields: ["first_name", "last_name", "age", "hobbies"],
      items: [
        { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: "Charles", last_name: "Macdonald", hobbies: "Reading↵ Singing" },
        { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: "Larsen", last_name: "Shaw", hobbies: "Surfing↵ Stamp Collecting↵ Games" }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myItems: function() {
      // iterate over items
      return this.items.map(item => {
        // copy current item
        const current = Object.assign({}, item);
        // iterate over item keys
        Object.keys(current).forEach(key => {
          // if value of this key is a string, replace
          if(typeof current[key] === 'string')
            current[key] = current[key].replace(/↵/g, '\n');
        });
        return current;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table striped hover :items="myItems" :fields="fields" style="white-space: pre-line;"></b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. But, when using the <pre>, the font of the text is changing. Is there any other way?

Comment: @SriVineeth I updated the answer to use ``css`` instead

Answer (score 1):

**Simply use CSS**

```
<style>
.table tbody tr td {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}
</style>
```

[image]

also, you need to use the computed prop, `:items="myItems"`

If you don't like the centering, then again use CSS with `text-align:left`, on both the header and the content.

```
<style>
.table thead tr th {
  text-align:left
}
.table tbody tr td {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  text-align:left
}
</style>
```